# PHP: Are these statements equivalent? (file_exists())

Tags: php, function

Aren't these equivalent?

==SCRIPT A==

```
if (file_exists($file) == false) {
     return false;
}
```

==SCRIPT B==

```
if(!file_exists($file)) {
     return false;
}
```

Comment: They are. What's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plain answer: **Y E S**

They evaluate to the same thing.

That first one might be even better suited like this:

```
if (file_exists($file) === false) { // === checks type and value
     return false;
}
```

OR:

```
return file_exists($file);
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, file_exists returns a boolean, so it's either true or false.

so you could return file_exists($file) as well...

Answer (score 1):

If you are making boolean comparisons, then you would rather do this:

```
if (file_exists($file) === false) {
    return false;
}
```

using the `===` operator, to ensure that what you are receiving is a variable of type *boolean* and of value equivalent to *false*.

Comment: Good point, but kind of irrelevant in this case as file_exists only returns a boolean to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

But if you would use:

```
if (file_exists($file) === false) {
    return false;
}
```

then it would not be the same as:

```
if(!file_exists($file)) {
    return false;
}
```

because in the first case it would check whether the value returned by function matches *strictly* to `false`, and in the second case the value returned by function would be *evaluated* to boolean value.

**EDIT:**

That is general rule.

But in case of `file_exists()` function, which returns boolean value, evaluating to boolean is not necessary, thus you can use strict condition and this will have the same result (but only in case you *know* the value will be either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking "what's the difference between the === and == operator" then:

'===' is a strict comparison that checks the types of both sides.
'==' is an 'equivalent to' comparison operator that will cast either side to the appropriate type if deemed necessary.

To expand, '==' can be used to check for 'falsey' values and '===' can be used to check for exact matches.

```
if (1 == TRUE) echo 'test';
>> "test"

if (1 === TRUE) echo 'test';
>>
```

If you're asking if there's any functional / practical difference between your two code blocks then no, there isn't and you should be returning as such: `return file_exists($file);`

Worth a read:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php